# Postgresql: How to use a WITH subquery with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables: `orders` and `contragents`. Each contragent might have many orders. Each order has an `order_date`. I want to get a first order date for each contragent, but with a caveat: if there was a gap between orders more than 180 days, I need to "forget" those before the gap (and thus the first order after the gap is considered "the first".

For this, I've implement a following statement:

```
with o1 as (
    select order_date, lag(order_date) over(order by order_date ASC) as prev_order_date 
    from orders o 
    where o.contragent_code = :code
    order by order_date desc) 
select o1.date_debts from o1
where extract(day from o1.order_date-o1.prev_order_date)>=180 or o1.prev_order_date is null 
order by order_date desc
limit 1
```

this results in a single value being returned for a contragent with code `code`, which is what I need.

But I *cannot* figure out how to run a select that would return this date for every contragent in a table!

The only way I was able to do it was using a `CREATE FUNCTION`, but I will be unable to do it on production, so.. any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add `partition by`, which is kinda like `group by` for `over`.

```
with o1 as (
    select order_date, lag(order_date) over(partition by contragent_code order by order_date ASC) as prev_order_date 
    from orders o 
    order by order_date desc) 
select o1.date_debts from o1
where extract(day from o1.order_date-o1.prev_order_date)>=180 or o1.prev_order_date is null 
order by order_date desc
```

Now `lag` looks for the previous order_date of rows with same contragent_code.

UPDATE: at the end, it appears that that was not exactly enough. This is the final statement:

```
with s as (
    select o.contragent_code, o.order_date, 
        case
        when
            extract(day from order_date-lag(order_date) over(partition by contragent_code order by order_date asc))>=180 
        then o.order_date else null
        end as date_with_gap
    from orders o 
) select contragent_code, coalesce(max(date_with_gap), min(order_date)) from s 
group by contragent_code
```